# Someone explain "AMUX" to me?

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-analysis, integrated-circuit, circuit-design

Have a rare case of an iPhone 6 with no display.

When I measure chest_pwr_en it's low at 1.1v should be 1.8v

[image]

I've removed the one cap on that line and even removed "chestnut" power display ic u1501 but still the voltage stays at 1.1v

Only other point that line goes to is to u1202 which is the main power management ic in the "AMUX" section which has to be what's pulling the voltage down from 1.8 to 1.1.

[image]

Anyone know what this section actually does? Is it sending or receiving the enable line?

Hope the pics are clear they're screenshots from the PDF on my phone

Comment: MUX usually means multiplexer. With an "A" in front it might mean analogue multiplexer.

Comment: What's it's purpose?

Comment: I have no idea what it does inside an iphone.

Comment: In general sense does it output signals or use input data? My research gives me conflicting explanations

Comment: Usually with a 8 to 1 mux with inputs labeled like this, AMUX_A0 thru A7 would be inputs, and AMUX_AY would be the output, selected with a 3-bit field somewhere.

Comment: @tcrosley Where would it output to generally? There is no other netlist for it just a test point

Comment: @ohmmy No, not just a test point, inputs AMUX_A0 through A7 have out AMUX_AY, and inputs B0 through B7 have output BY.  The only unconnected nets are A0/A1 and B2/B3, all four are inputs.  It's typical not to have all inputs on a mux connected.